# User-Defined Table Types Documentation in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I tried to find the documentation for user-defined table types in SQL Server 2012 but could only find the 2008 R2 documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx).

I know they can be used in SQL Server 2012 but should I considered them as bad practise or obsolete if there is no documentation for SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Not a bad practice at all, in fact it was a very interesting/useful enhancement in  2008, which made us able to pass tables to a stored procedure rather than depending on cursors to loop through records. I am not aware of any draw backs of using table types in stored procedures.

Comment: Generally speaking, a page not being available in "other versions" on TechNet just means that they haven't updated their documentation, not that the feature is being/has been phased out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User defined table types are in 2012 and 2014. In SSMS look under Programmability/Types and you will see a tab for User Defined Table Types.

Comment: As I mentioned I know they can be used in 21012, I am just wondering if no documentation for Sql Server 2012 means anything.

Comment: Microsoft will announce that a feature is going to be 'deprecated' a few versions before they actually remove it. There has been no mention that defined table types are going to be deprecated.